# How can I retrieve the property values of a class attribute?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Is it possible to retrieve public members from a custom attribute class in c#. Consider the following attribute class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false)]
public class ModuleMessageHandlerAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type type { get; set; }

    public ModuleMessageHandlerAttribute(Type type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

And i have some handler classes as following which use this attribute:

```
[ModuleMessageHandler(typeof(HelloModule))]
    public class HelloMessageHandler : IMessageHandler<Hello>
    {
    }
```

Next i need to access the Type property of the **ModuleMessageHandlerAttribute**class to compare if the Type matches a specific class.

Comment: What is the meaning of `access the "type" property from all classes which use this attribute`? Explain more..

Comment: Does type property exist inside the class? how are you using it on other class? if you just pass the value to the ModuleMessageHandler you should be able to pass the vlaue.

This part "I want to access the "type" property from all classes which use this attribute."
 doesnt make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use reflection for the purpose

```
var result = assembly.GetTypes()
                     .Where(x=> x.GetCustomAttributes<ModuleMessageHandlerAttribute>().Any())
                     .Select(x=>x.GetCustomAttribute<ModuleMessageHandlerAttribute>().type);
```

[Sample Code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fkrGLC)

If you want to retrieve all public properties of Attribute, then you could use

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,object>>> GetTypesAttribute<T>(Assembly assembly) where T:Attribute
{

   return assembly.GetTypes().Where(x=> x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T)).Any())
                            .Select(x=> x.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(T)))
                            .Select(x=> x.GetType().GetProperties().Select(c=> new KeyValuePair<string,object>(c.Name,c.GetValue(x))));
}
```

You could now use the method as

```
GetTypesAttribute<ModuleMessageHandlerAttribute>(assembly);
```

[Sample Code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/moNLsA)

Answer (score 4):

You mean like this:

```
[ModuleMessageHandler(typeof(SomeType))]
class SomeClass
{
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        ModuleMessageHandlerAttribute attribute = GetType()
            .GetCustomAttribute<ModuleMessageHandlerAttribute>();
        Type type = attribute.type;
    }
}
```